# Prove convergence without ratio test and root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What hint could you give me to prove the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^3}{2^k} $ without using ratio test and root test?
I tried bounding it by a geometric series but I can't think of any that actually works. I only found out that after $ k=10, \ a_k$ is $<1$ so I also thought of bounding it after a certain $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: **Hint:** $k^3<1.1^k$ for sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: of course, thank you so much

Comment: Note that it is more or less equivalent to root test, i.e $\sqrt[k]{k^3}\to 1< 1.1$, even if you don't want it...

Comment: yeah that's true. the thing is: we haven't seen root and ratio test in the lecture but in an old exam this question was asked, so I wondered how you could solve it without root and ratio test